# How would you explain that Ubuntu is fine for many people

Tags: community

How would you explain that Ubuntu if fine for most people who just want to browse the web, write e-mail, and so on?

Comment: [You do everything through a browser now ...](http://xkcd.com/934/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

People are so entrenched in using Windows that telling them ubuntu is better for their basic tasks is not enough, you have **to show** them how ubuntu can be better/easier performing whatever it is they are trying to accomplish.

You can set up a fully configured Ubuntu box for them and show the differences on their daily usage.

You can show to them how a particular Ubuntu / linux app is more suited / easier / cheaper
for them.

Comment: You can use a Live CD to demo the possibilities.

Comment: thats a good idea. :)

Comment: Run some basic windows apps using wine to demonstrate that *nix can still run any windows apps they're attached to and don't touch flash video online with a 10ft pole (unless it actually works well on your computer). If you want a safe bet goto YouTube (since it uses HTML5 video).

Comment: you could also set up a virtual machine with their original windows setup as fall back in case ...

Answer (score 8):

I like to bring along a non-technical person, and have them explain Ubuntu is fine.

You can argue until you're blue in the face, but most people will just think, "Well, you're a technical person, of course it's easy for you."  But when someone that they consider a peer who has their same (or less) computer experience tells them in a heartfelt way, "Ubuntu is plenty good", that's the best sales pitch.

Answer (score 5):

This is the sort of question better directed to the [Ubuntu Marketing Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MarketingTeam) - not only is it their entire reason for being, but they can also provide materials, mentoring and research data to back up assertions.

In particular you should read the [Activism Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ActivismGuide) and look at the materials available  on the [Spread Ubuntu](http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/) site.

I personally like to show people the [Ubunchu! manga](http://www.ubunchu.net/), it goes over well in my social circles.

Answer (score 4):

Let the people forget about the os! Nobody works with the os. As you write in your question it goes about writing e-mail or browsing the web: there are the applications who are curcial. So, firefox is know very well to browse the web but what email-client would you promote?

If these apps are usable on windows, like firefox, let the people try them and if it comes to the point that they should pay for an app like outlook people reminds that there exists an app for free.

Time comes where a computer must be replaced and that will also be a point of decision. If the experience with the apps are positive it will be a small step to save some money and choose a free os.

Answer (score 3):

Just show them.

Remember that Ubuntu is different, but you need it to be *better* for people to consider it.  Much like switching from a right-hand scissor to a left-hand scissor.  Can do the same, but is different, and it needs to be *better* to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

I would just show them the efficiency of ubuntu on my dual boot machine with windows and to compare the difference for themselve.

Answer (score 2):

I like to show them Compiz. :)

Answer (score 1):

How you did know that yourself? If someone told you and it worked, it's very likely that it works for some other people :) Let them to try it for themselves, help them to clean that «uncleanable» virus in their pendrive, show them that great Compiz effect... and tell them they also can do that easily.

Also, you may want to join a [LoCo Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/) near you and get involved in spreading Ubuntu in your community.

Comment: I'm a programmer, just by the nature of that occupation I'm tech savvy.